# Centos 7 Slow Resolve

Tags: centos, dns

After installing Centos 7, I noticed that DNS lookups for addresses saved in /etc/hosts take long time, here is example:

```
time curl -X get http://localhost

real    0m0.159s
user    0m0.004s
sys     0m0.005s
```

but

```
time curl -X get http://127.0.0.1

real    0m0.005s
user    0m0.001s
sys     0m0.003s
```

It takes ~ 0.15 secs to resolve "localhost" by each request.

I make the same tests on another server in the same network with Centos 6.5 but "localhost" is as fast as "127.0.0.1"

Comment: Compare `/etc/nsswitch.conf` on the two servers.

Comment: @jordanm i did replaced this file from the other server to this one, but no use.

Answer (score 2):

It's Red Hat [Bug 1130239 - Difference in curl performance between RHEL6 and RHEL7](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1130239):

> The `libcurl` library used an unnecessarily long blocking delay
>   for actions with no active file descriptors, even for short operations. 
>   This meant that some actions, such as resolving a host name
>   using `/etc/hosts`, took an artificially long time to complete. 
>   The blocking code in `libcurl` has now been modified
>   so that the initial delay is short,
>   and gradually increases until an event occurs. 
>   Fast `libcurl` operations now complete more quickly.

Install new version curl from source:

```
git clone https://github.com/bagder/curl.git
cd curl
yum install libtool
./buildconf
./configure
make
make install
```